# Perl "unlink" function usge with "glob"

Tags: perl

I want to delete files with "1.1.1.1" ip address in `/tmp` folder:

```
# ls -1 /tmp
1.1.1.1_Reboot.xml
1.1.1.1_Roll.xml
1.1.1.1_Setup.xml
1.1.1.2_Reboot.xml
1.1.1.2_Roll.xml
1.1.1.2_Setup.xml
```

I am referring: [unlink](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html) and [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $DIR     = "/tmp";
my $IP      = '1.1.1.1';

unlink glob $DIR."/".$IP."*";
```

However, it is not deleting the files. My suspicion is on the `glob` function and I guess I am not using it in the right fashion.

Could you help.
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

if I replace `$IP` with the ip address itself, then it is deleting the files.

```
unlink glob $DIR."/"."1.1.1.1"."*";
```

So, It looks like the `unlink` statement is not able to evaluate the value of variable `$IP`. I do not know why it is behaving this way. I need to make it work with `$IP` and not its explicit value.

Answer (score 0):

It may be retated to the path. Print the error to get more information. Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $DIR     = "/tmp";
my $IP      = '1.1.1.1';

chdir $DIR;
my @goners  = glob $IP . "*";

foreach my $file ( @goners ) {
   print "file: $file\n";
   next unless $file =~ m!^1\.1\.1\.\d_!;
   print "file to delete: $file\n";
   unlink $file or warn "Could not unlink $file: $!";
}
```

Comment: I added a set of print sentences that may helps you. And I check the issue that @ikegami pointed